# calling an array containing variable int and String

Tags: java

I'm working on a simple product inventory program that allows the user to keep track of a store inventory. I'm using OOP so my program consists of 2 classes one is the class products{} that contains the variables and an initial print method. The second class is called class productdatafinder {} and it contains a long table that contains the inventory information in the form shown bellow:

```
class  productsDataFinder
{
   public static void main( String[] not_in_use )
   {
      products[]  products_table  =
      {
//Milk products:
         new products( 3333, "Cheese",   "milk product", 1, "A" ),
         new products( 6778, "Butter",    "milk product", 1, "A" ),
         new products( 5642, "Yougurt", "milk product", 1, "A" ),
         new products( 4453, "High fat milk",   "milk product", 1, "A"  ), 
         new products( 3423, "Low fat milk",   "milk product", 1, "A" ),
         new products( 2296, "Coco milk","milk product", 1, "A" ),
         new products( 1796, "Fruit yougurt",  "milk product", 1, "A"   ),

//Fruits:    
         new products( 4379, "Apple",    "Fruit", 3, "B"    ),
```

and here is how they are defined in order: int product_id; String product_name; String product_group; int product_aisle; String product_row;

Now my question:

I already know how to print out each product information giving the product_id which is of type int but now I want to do the same by giving the product_name which is of type String. How can I do this? I'm looking for some tips and hits or any useful web links. Here is the programs output:

```
 This program prints out your inventory data. 
 The serial number is in the form of (1-9)(1-9)(1-9)(1-9) 
 Insert your serial number: 3333

    Your product id is: 3333
    Your product name is: Cheese
    Your product group is: milk product
    Your product aisle number is: 1
    Your product row number is: A

Process completed
```

Thank you and sorry for the long text

here is my print method for variable product_id. This one is in the first class

```
public void print_products_data()
   {
      System.out.print( "\n    Your product id is: "  +  product_id  +
                        "\n    Your product name is: " +  product_name  +
                        "\n    Your product group is: " + product_group +
                        "\n    Your product aisle number is: " + product_aisle +
                        "\n    Your product row number is: " + product_row) ;
```

and here is the second one

```
System.out.print("\n This program prints out your inventory data. "
                     + "\n The serial number is in the form of (1-9)(1-9)(1-9)(1-9) "
                     + "\n Insert your serial number: "  ) ;

      Scanner  keyboard  =  new Scanner( System.in ) ;
      int  given_id  =  keyboard.nextInt() ;

      int  products_index  =  0 ;

      boolean table_search_ready  =  false ;

         while ( table_search_ready  ==  false )
         {

         if ( products_index >= products_table.length )
         {

            table_search_ready  =  true ;

                      System.out.print( "\n    Sorry, no such product id "
                           +  given_id  + ".\n" ) ;
         }

         else if ( products_table[ products_index ].get_id()  ==  given_id )
         {
            products_table[ products_index ].print_products_data() ;

            table_search_ready  =  true ;
         }



         else
         {
            products_index  ++  ;
         }
```

Comment: The procss would be exactly the same as with the ID. Just make sure to compare Strings with `a.equals(b)` and not with `a == b`.

Comment: Have you tried `products_table[index].getName().equals(desiredName)`?

Comment: Show how you are printing

Comment: You might want to place all your products in two `java.util.Map`s (e.g. `HashMap`s) and use the id as key for one map and the String as key for the other map. Arrays aren't really suitable for efficient lookups.
So the tip is: Look up on how to use hash tables. The general concept is explained here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table
That aside, in Java it's considered good style to capitalize class names and use lowercase variable names: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would operate the same way that your current lookup system operates. However, instead of checking the product_id, check the product_name (or any other attribute).

```
//returns the Product which matches the name given by the parameter
//only works for unique names
public Product nameLookup(String name){
    for(Product p: products_table){
        if(name.equals(p.getProductName()))
            return p;
    }
}

//If names are not unique
public ArrayList<Product> nameLookup(String name){
    List<Product> templist = new ArrayList<Product>();
    for(Product p: products_table){
        if(name.equals(p.getProductName()))
            templist.add(p);
    }
    return templist;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The .equals() method is probably what you are looking for. You could have something like this to test if it works for you

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter product: ");
if(input.nextLine().equals(products_table[0].productName){//or getProductName() if you have that
    //print product data
}
```

Edit: here is the link to the javadoc page where the .equals() method is described. Also maybe take a look at .equalsIgnoreCase() so that the user can InpUT WhATevEr hE wANTs!

[String javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Answer (score 0):

While iterating through the product_table, call you print method by equals test.

```
String name="XYZ";
for(int i=0;i<product_table.length;i++) {
if(name.equals(products_table[i].getProduct_name())) {
  //Call print on products_table[i]
}
}
```